# Updating Anaconda fails with Remove Error

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, geopandas, osmnx

I was having trouble using Conda Forge to install packages, namely GeoPandas and OSMNX. It kept getting stuck on "solving environment."

So I was trying to update my Anaconda distribution hoping that would solve the problem.

I've tried `conda update --all`, `conda update anaconda`, and `conda update conda`

Each of these fails with the same issue:

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: failed

RemoveError: 'setuptools' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from
conda's operating environment.
```

Here's the full output:

```
Aschs-MacBook-Air-2:~ aschharwood$ conda update conda
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /anaconda

  added / updated specs:
    - conda


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    asn1crypto-0.24.0          |           py36_0         154 KB
    cffi-1.12.1                |   py36hb5b8e2f_0         212 KB
    chardet-3.0.4              |           py36_1         189 KB
    cryptography-2.5           |   py36ha12b0ac_0         590 KB
    idna-2.8                   |           py36_0         133 KB
    pip-19.0.3                 |           py36_0         1.9 MB
    pycosat-0.6.3              |   py36h1de35cc_0         107 KB
    pycparser-2.19             |           py36_0         173 KB
    pyopenssl-19.0.0           |           py36_0          81 KB
    ruamel_yaml-0.11.14        |   py36h9d7ade0_2         192 KB
    setuptools-40.8.0          |           py36_0         622 KB
    six-1.12.0                 |           py36_0          22 KB
    wheel-0.33.1               |           py36_0          39 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         4.3 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  pip                pkgs/main/osx-64::pip-19.0.3-py36_0
  setuptools         pkgs/main/osx-64::setuptools-40.8.0-py36_0
  six                pkgs/main/osx-64::six-1.12.0-py36_0

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  asn1crypto            pkgs/free::asn1crypto-0.22.0-py36_0 --> pkgs/main::asn1crypto-0.24.0-py36_0
  cffi                        pkgs/free::cffi-1.10.0-py36_0 --> pkgs/main::cffi-1.12.1-py36hb5b8e2f_0
  chardet                   pkgs/free::chardet-3.0.4-py36_0 --> pkgs/main::chardet-3.0.4-py36_1
  cryptography                         2.4.2-py36ha12b0ac_0 --> 2.5-py36ha12b0ac_0
  idna                           pkgs/free::idna-2.6-py36_0 --> pkgs/main::idna-2.8-py36_0
  pycparser                pkgs/free::pycparser-2.18-py36_0 --> pkgs/main::pycparser-2.19-py36_0
  pyopenssl              pkgs/free::pyopenssl-17.0.0-py36_0 --> pkgs/main::pyopenssl-19.0.0-py36_0
  ruamel_yaml         pkgs/free::ruamel_yaml-0.11.14-py36_1 --> pkgs/main::ruamel_yaml-0.11.14-py36h9d7ade0_2
  wheel                      pkgs/free::wheel-0.29.0-py36_0 --> pkgs/main::wheel-0.33.1-py36_0

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  pycosat            conda-forge::pycosat-0.6.3-py36h470a2~ --> pkgs/main::pycosat-0.6.3-py36h1de35cc_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages
pyopenssl-19.0.0     | 81 KB     | ##################################### | 100% 
setuptools-40.8.0    | 622 KB    | ##################################### | 100% 
cryptography-2.5     | 590 KB    | ##################################### | 100% 
asn1crypto-0.24.0    | 154 KB    | ##################################### | 100% 
ruamel_yaml-0.11.14  | 192 KB    | ##################################### | 100% 
pycosat-0.6.3        | 107 KB    | ##################################### | 100% 
six-1.12.0           | 22 KB     | ##################################### | 100% 
cffi-1.12.1          | 212 KB    | ##################################### | 100% 
wheel-0.33.1         | 39 KB     | ##################################### | 100% 
idna-2.8             | 133 KB    | ##################################### | 100% 
pycparser-2.19       | 173 KB    | ##################################### | 100% 
chardet-3.0.4        | 189 KB    | ##################################### | 100% 
pip-19.0.3           | 1.9 MB    | ##################################### | 100% 
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: failed

RemoveError: 'setuptools' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from
conda's operating environment.
```

Comment: Everybody complains about conda /solving environment.

Comment: I also had the same issue with old version of anaconda. Installation of latest version of anaconda fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

Per the [OSMnx docs](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#installation), if you have any trouble, try installing in a virtual environment:

```
conda create --override-channels -c conda-forge -n OSMNX python=3 osmnx
source activate OSMNX
```

Comment: The problem stem from, I think, installing OSmnx via pip because conda was getting stuck on "solving environment." (Admittedly, I did not read the installation docs carefully.) Immediately after,  when I tried to use Geopandas, I got the error: "OSError: Could not find libspatialindex_c library file." Geopandas had always worked before, so I'm assuming that this is related to how I installed OSmnx. Let me know if I should post this as it's own thread.